# Browser action height won't reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on an extension that will give you a response based on your text, this works and is good and all, but the height of the browser action won't reset.

To try to fix this, I have attempted to resize the window using window.resizeTo and tried to manually set the height of both 'html' and 'body' using jQuery. Nothing has worked. Is this a bug with Google Chrome or am I doing something wrong? **This does not make it work, as it stays at the same size.**

As you can see in the pictures, the window starts out perfectly sized and then I enter a question and go back to the window being larger than it was initially.

[image: The beginning size]

[image: Changes to size of response window][image: Height wont go back]

Comment: @wOxxOm if you actually read my post, you would see that I described that as it does not work

Comment: Works here. The only *obvious* case when it doesn't is when there's a taller inner element as per CSS Box Model.

Comment: @wOxxOm I set the height of a blank browser action to 600px and then back to 0px, and it didn't resize. Seems to be a problem with Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm As you can see, the html height is 0px, but the action is still at 152px http://i.imgur.com/l9C69Ge.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92331/discussion-between-woxxom-and-adam-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup can't become smaller than its content and/or CSS allows.

Find the element and/or CSS rule that occupies the full height by inspecting the popup (right-click it and choose `Inspect popup`), point over various elements inside `<body>` to see them highlighted and their actual height displayed. If all the elements are smaller than the popup it could only mean that you have a CSS rule on `<body>` or `<html>` that specifies the minimum height. If possible, remove that rule from the CSS or override it.

The problem in your case was a CSS rule `html {min-height: 100%}` in one of the 3rd party styles.

Set both `height` and `min-height` for `body` and `html`, for example like this:

```
document.body.style.height = '0px';
document.body.style.minHeight = '0px';
document.documentElement.style.height = '0px';
document.documentElement.style.minHeight = '0px';
```

Or use `'auto'` instead of `'0px'`.